# QT C++ Reading Custom File Structures

Tags: c++, qt

How would I read and store the data of a line of text in a text file for example that went like:
Bob 13 14 21

In other words how would I set a string variable equal to Bob, and then two integer variables for 13 and 14 if that was the line from a text file. I would really appreciate any input.

Comment: what you want it's called `serialization`

Comment: You do know about the [C++ input/output subsystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) and the input operator `>>`?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=c%2B%2B+qt+serialization

Comment: Yeah but the whenever I do something like file >> name >> one >> two >> three, I get an error of no match for "'operator >>'(operand types are 'QFile' and 'QString"

Comment: there are a lot of answers to this on both the internet and on SO, do a simple search.

Comment: But im trying to read from a text file

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "[c++] read file parse variable".  This kind of question is almost asked daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two paradigms for this:  1) let the object read its members; 2) have a function read the members.

With the first paradigm, you overload the stream extraction `operator>>` to input each field in the object.  This should be recursive for non-POD members in the class.

Templates can be used to overload `operator>>` for reading types.

You could also search and read about "serialization".